# SoundManager2 SWF plugin messes up scrollbar (only in Google Chrome)

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, flash, soundmanager2

Not sure if this is a Google Chrome bug, a SoundManager issue or I am doing something wrong. It only happens in Google Chrome and **only** when Flash is enabled.

I have a parent `<div>` with `overflow-y: auto`.

When [SoundManager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) loads, it creates a new `<div>` element `#sm2-container` at the bottom of the page.
On `$(window).load()`, I reposition that element like this:

```
$("#sm2-container").css({position: "absolute", top: "0px", zIndex: "10"});
```

However, the scrollbar appears messed up:

[image: Scroll Issue Present]

When I disable Flash or "display:none" the `#sm2-container`, it looks and acts normally, but I have no sound:

[image: Scroll Issue Gone]

You can see the issue live [here](http://pote.ca/bible/read/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitely looks like a Chrome bug for me too, because scroll bar is only *displayed* shifted, in order to scroll I have to aim mouse at where it must be placed.

**A fix:** By setting `$('#sm2-container').css('z-index','-10');` I can hide it and this fixes scroll bar in Chrome.
Sound still plays OK (as I understand, controls for it are in right panel so it is OK for it to be hidden).

Should something be visible in `#sm2-container`? It looks empty for me, only by right-clicking it displays Flash menu.